# "u" property within an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

Since I cannot search for this with meaningful results, I can't be sure that this is not a duplicate.

However, I am running a JSSOR Slider on my site and some of the elements have a u property for example:

```
<div  u="slides" style="cursor: move;
position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:
1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
```

This "u=slides" is throwing up an error when I run it through a W3 Validator, however when I remove this property from the element, the slider no longer functions.

I am wondering the purpose of this property as I see no markup for it anywhere, and wondering if it can be substituted for anything in order to make the site pass markup validation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's used somewhere in javascript?

Comment: ok what is your issue?

Comment: use a slider plugin that doesn't rely on invalid custom attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom attributes (in HTML5) can be assigned to elements using [the `data-*` prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

```html
<elem data-u="slides"></elem>
```

The problem here, however, is that whoever developed this JSSOR Slider plugin has decided not to use valid HTML5 markup. Unless the plugin's JavaScript code is modified to look for a `data-*` attribute rather than an invalid attribute named "u", you will not be able to modify this attribute without breaking the way your site functions.

---

**Update:** Digging deeper I've discovered that this was already raised as an issue on JSSOR's GitHub repository back in January: https://github.com/jssor/jquery-slider/issues/4. They've rectified this by allowing you to use a valid `data-u` attribute instead of `u`.

### The Solution

Provided your JSSOR plugin code is up to date. You can simply modify your HTML to:

```
<div data-u="slides" style="...">
```